# How can I set the number of OpenMP threads from within the program?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, openmp

Running the program as

```
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./a.out
```

limits the number of active OpenMP threads to 4, as evidenced by `htop`. However, if instead of binding the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable in `Bash`, I call

```
setenv("OMP_NUM_THREADS", "4", 1);
```

from `main` before calling any OpenMP-enabled functions, this seems to have no effect.

Why is this happening? How can I set the number of OpenMP threads from within the program, if it's possible at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two ways<sup>1</sup> one can use to set the number of threads from within the program:

#### Option #1

Use `num_threads` clause in a directive that opens a parallel region:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(number_of_threads)
```

#### Option #2

Use `omp_set_num_threads` API function **before** a parallel region begins:

```
#include <omp.h>

// ...
omp_set_num_threads(number_of_threads);
#pragma omp parallel
```

*Note: Both options take priority over OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable, but `num_threads` clause has precedence over `omp_set_num_threads`.*

> *Why setenv fails to have any effect?*

This is covered in the [OpenMP specification](http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications/) (emphasis mine):

> ### Chapter 4
>
> #### Environment Variables
>
> [...] Modifications to the environment variables **after the program has started, even if modified by the program itself, are ignored** by the OpenMP implementation. However, the settings of some of the ICVs can be modified during the execution of the OpenMP program by the use of the appropriate directive clauses or OpenMP API routines. [...]

---

<sub><sup>1)</sup> There is a third run-time option that allows to alter the number of threads executing a parallel region that follows by resetting it to `1` (master thread only) or to the number from `num_threads` clause or `omp_set_num_threads` call, which is an `if` clause in a directive the clause belongs to.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why setenv fails to have any effect?

Comment: Hi Piotr Skotnicki, I have been trying to apply the two solutions mentioned here to set the number of OpenMP threads to 1. When I set the environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS=1, the program is limited to one thread. But when I add the above mentioned solutions to the top of programs main function, I still get multiple threads running. Is there anything that I am doing wrong??.

Comment: Ahh, it was an OpenBlas issue. Setting OMP_NUM_THREADS also sets OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS. If the issue is with OpenBlas spawning multiple threads instead of OpenMP then building OpenBlas again with https://github.com/bgeneto/build-install-compile-openblas will fix the issue.