# Set OpenMP threads for all dependencies in R package

Tags: r, openmp, r-package, mclapply

I'm developing an R package which uses `parallel::mclapply` and several other library dependencies which possibly rely upon OpenMP.

Unfortunately, some functions explode with memory usage, making the R package practically unusable.

I've noticed that if I set `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` before starting R, the memory is far more manageable.

My question is, if there a way for me to achieve this behavior within the R package itself?

My initial try was to use `R/zzz.R` and an `.onLoad()` function to load these global variables.

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname){
  Sys.setenv(OMP_NUM_THREADS=1)  
}
```

But this doesn't work. The memory still explodes.

I'm worried that this cannot be done within an R package itself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27320691/5269850

> Modifications to the environment variables **after the program has**
> **started**, even if modified by the program itself, **are ignored** by the
> OpenMP implementation.

Is there a recommended approach for this problem when writing R packages?

Comment: The general answer is there is no general answer. There is nothing to stop a package from hardcoding the number of threads to use. Most packages *ought* to default to 1, and respect most OMP environment variables, but the only reliable way is to go through each dependency and choose its particular method of setting threads.

Comment: To be slightly more helpful, if you are talking about limiting the thread usage within (the compiled code within) your own package, that can be done. And if you are wanting to know how to set the number of threads for a particular package, that can also be done. If the latter, specify which dependencies appear to be causing grief; if the former, provide (an MRE of) your C/C++/Fortran code.

Comment: @Hugh How would you do this: "f you are talking about limiting the thread usage within (the compiled code within) your own package, that can be done."? Do you have examples?

Comment: @Hugh "There is nothing to stop a package from hardcoding the number of threads to use" Do you know if there's a way to explicitly set this for the `parallel` package?

Comment: `parallel` package should be fine. For one's own package, I'd need to say some of your C/C++/Fortran code, but as an example `#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nThread)` where `int nThread` is specified as an argument would allow you to set the number of threads directly.